# ImportError - Python Relative Import in Ubuntu

Tags: python, macos, ubuntu-12.04

I'm facing a new problem with relative imports in Python (2.7). 
I have a mac (with Snow Leopard) and another computer running Ubuntu (12.04). Both computers are using Python 2.7. 
I wrote some code in python using relative imports and was able to run it without any problems by doing:

```
python -m package.subpackage1.file.py
```

I have exactly the same code on my other computer (I used SVN) and when I tried to run it by typing:

```
python -m package.subpackage1.file.py
```

I got the error:

```
ImportError: No module named subpackage2.file2
```

Nothing has changed between the code I use for Mac and the code I use for Linux.

So does anyone already encountered this problem and/ or would have an idea to fix this?

Comment: Have you checked the `$PYTHONPATH` on the two machines? Is your Mac importing the directory where `subpackage2` is defined by default, and your Linux box doesn't?

Comment: When I type "echo $PYTHONPATH" in both computer the variable looks empty and when I start python and do:
>> import sys
>> sys.path

all the paths are related to packages included in python or to packages such as numpy I added later ( for both computers); But none of them import a directory where subpackage2 is defined.

Comment: OK. Where is `subpackage2` on your Mac? On your Linux?

Comment: In both computers it is in:  ~/SVN-FOLDER/MyProject/package/subpackage2

where '~' is the root folder (the one where I am when I start the terminal)

Comment: It never hurts to verify with "svn status" and "svn info" commands to make sure things are absolutely identical.  Also, which os isn't working, OSX or Linux?

Comment: Thank you very much! the SVN advice seems to have fix the problem. I really thought files were identical but apparently not because when I did 'svn info' revision numbers were not the same. So I updated the Linux files and now it works! 
I still don't understand why the versions were not identical because I tried several times to update on both sides when it was not working. Anyhow, it works now, thanks a lot!!!